# Is this Mealy FSM representation correct for 00111?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequential-logic, sequence-detector

Is this Mealy FSM representation correct for a non-overlapping input bit sequence detector for the sequence 00111?

[image]

Comment: Please format the picture better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this Mealy FSM representation is correct for a non-overlapping input bit sequence detector for the sequence 00111.

I don't see any problem, at least with the small number of cases I tried in my head.

But, you now need a way to *prove* that the diagram is correct, other than by inspection from some stranger on the internet.  This depends on how you intend to implement your design.  But, some form of simulation is always a good approach before creating an actual circuit.

To demonstrate that the diagram is correct, you can run this [Verilog simulation on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/vkux).  It shows several example input data streams, but you can change the input sequence to whatever you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Could you please show me a diagram

Comment: @NDT_D: I mean that I think your diagram is correct.

Comment: @NDT_D: I posted a link to a simulation that you can run to help convince you that the diagram is correct.